What is a good picture for the "Page not found" webpage of Biblical Hermeneutics?
The Biblical Hermeneutics site has a nondescript default "404" image for its "Page not found":

But the Christianity site has a very suitable picture below for its "Page not found" (404) webpage, which turns out to be an oil painting by Frank Ordaz he called The Empty Tomb.

so does the Judaism site:

The English site has a suitable picture as well (an engraving from the book Alice's Adventures in Wonderland), consistent with the theme of the site:

plus a cute one for the superuser site:

Question: What would be a good picture for Biblical Hermeneutics' own "Page not found" webpage?

Two ideas: one of the lost books, like the Book of the Wars of the Lord. (The Book of Jasher might be the most famous, but is a bad example because there are multiple forgeries. Second idea is a damaged manuscript like this: https://bible-papyrus.github.io/jrl020153trback.jpg

Enoch walked with God, then he was no more.
—Genesis 5:24
I just mocked this up; that's Genesis 5 in the background...


That works :-) ...

Genesis 5 in Hebrew as background is perfect for BH.SE.
